# How can i print all content of one Array in one line?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'me new here and beginner of JAVA.
I've just started learning about **Scanner and Array!**

I want to get some input from Scanner. and save it into Array. 
the array size is 5 and I succeed save those 
but what I could print is only one value from array.
I want to print all values in the array
and I have no idea what should I do or where I should fix!
hope you guys tell me about that.

My code is down below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import jdk.internal.util.xml.impl.Input;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[5];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("five numbers");

        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int nums : array) {
            System.out.print(nums);
        }

    }
}
```

### this is result :

five numbers1 2 3 5 5

Comment: and after put "1 2 3 5 5" in there, nothing happened.  if i put 5numbers in the array,                                                                                             for (int nums : array) {
            System.out.print(nums);
        }    <--------i thought this part will be print all contents, but it was not

Comment: Yes, i did and unfortunately, still nothing happened after put 5numbers in array........... System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array)); ---> does not work,            for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) --->neither, :( but thank you.

Comment: Oh it is work now! thank you so much.

Comment: and i missed one of your answer. i didn't intend ignoring your message. anyway thank you alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the following iteration which is expecting 6 numbers (since `i` starts at 0 and ends at 5).

**This wont work :**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
```

**This will work**

You should either input 6 numbers and change your array size to 6 elements. Either ways, you need to change the for loop to :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)'$'
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)'$'
```

as you want it to loop 5 times.

Comment: You please Ignore '$'.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you defined an array of size 5:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

**BUT** you expect for  6 input numbers, as the `for-loop` set to loop 6 time due to `<=`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

**The solution** here is to change the condition to `i < array.length`

Explanation:

1. By definition:

   Array size is 5

   `array.length` = 5
2. inside the for-loop: `array[i] = scanner.nextInt()`, when `i = array.length` i.e. `i=5`, `array[i]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 
either

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: How does `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));` fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

i don't think you need to use

```
import jdk.internal.util.xml.impl.Input;
```

package file.
and change the loop statement

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

otherwise it will rise an error when you will put 6th input like:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer? And no, the code won't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at all..

Comment: sorry, it is same, it is my first answer so i just don't know how to write and how to use bold words and other things so it took time.

Comment: yes nothing happened because it asks for 6th input also according to his loop condition. he did not asked for 6th input but he put condition like it want 6 input from user.

Comment: i am just replying your answer, you already solved his problem. i am just telling what will happen if i give 6th input also.